# Remove a particular character from the end of each string

Tags: r

How can I remove "/" from the end of my data. Let's assume this is my data

```
#input 
ID    page
 1    www.example.com/, ww.example.com/flight, www.example.com/flight/
 2    www.example.com/, ww.example.com/flight
```

I wish to remove "/" from those who had as their last character and my output will be like that

```
 #output 
 ID    page
 1    www.example.com, ww.example.com/flight, www.example.com/flight
 2    www.example.com, ww.example.com/flight
```

Comment: perhaps `gsub("/(?=,|$)", "", as.character(df$page), perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Also have a look at `urltools` package. It has some great functions for working with URLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gsub` without the lookarounds..  Here, we remove the `/` followed by either at the end of the string (`$`) or a `,` and replace it with `,`.  In the subsequent `sub` we remove the `,` at the end.

```
df1$page <- sub(",$", "", gsub("/($|,)", ",", df1$page))

df1$page
#[1] "www.example.com, ww.example.com/flight, www.example.com/flight" 
#[2] "www.example.com, ww.example.com/flight"
```

Or another option is

```
 gsub("/(?!\\b)", "", df1$page, perl = TRUE)
 #[1] "www.example.com, ww.example.com/flight, www.example.com/flight" 
 #[2] "www.example.com, ww.example.com/flight"
```

Answer (score 7):

One option:

```
gsub("/(?=,|$)", "", as.character(df$page), perl = TRUE)
#[1] "www.example.com, ww.example.com/flight, www.example.com/flight"
#[2] "www.example.com, ww.example.com/flight"
```

This checks if a `/` is followed by either a comma `,` or the end of the string `$` and if that is found, the `/` is replaced by `""`, i.e. it is removed. Since this is a lookbehind, we use `perl = TRUE`.

Other option (less efficient):

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$page), ", ", fixed = TRUE), function(x) toString(sub("/$", "", x)))
#[1] "www.example.com, ww.example.com/flight, www.example.com/flight"
#[2] "www.example.com, ww.example.com/flight"
```